# Trying to get an AngularJS / SCSS codepen to run locally...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/jjmartucci/pen/DlCmy

I'm using Brackets. I copied and pasted the CSS into my style.css, the JS into my init.js, and the HTML part into the body of my index.html...
I also modified the head of my HTML document to say:

```
    <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular-scenario.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular-mocks.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular-bootstrap-prettify.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular-bootstrap-prettify.js"></script>

</head>
```

and I'm still struggling to get it going. The CSS seems to be working, but the functionality is messed up. Is there any obvious step I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You're loading way too many instances of the same scripts. And your `init.js` needs to come after your 3rd party libraries.

Try this:

```
<head>
    <!-- style -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

    <!-- libs -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular-scenario.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular-mocks.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular-bootstrap-prettify.min.js"></script>

    <!-- app -->
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Hmmmm, thank you, but it doesn't work still. I suppose there is too much going on here for me to grasp. Do you have any other suggestions, or should I call it quits on this codepen, haha?

Comment: Might help to move `init.js` into the `<body>` tag. Are you seeing any JS errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

While copying javascript from codepen, it may be adding some addition checks whilst compiling the coffeescript. So just use http://js2.coffee/ in order to convert the coffeescript into javascript preview, which you can then use in your code own code. Hopefully this solves the javascript problems.

Comment: Links to third party applications/plugins is frowned upon by the Stack Overflow community. Stack overflow is geared towards getting source code solution examples as assistance to help people debug code they have written.

Comment: Well im afraid I cannot do it myself? You need to use the plugin so I do not see the problem? I answered the questions providing support.... This is a similar question btw which also uses this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320425/custom-svg-signature-works-on-codepen-but-not-on-local-machine-what-is-wrong