# Custom SVG signature works on CODEPEN but not on local machine- what is wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, mamp

I tried to copy the following code from codepen http://codepen.io/ghepting/pen/xnezB to try and run it on my localhost machine. In codepen, as you can see the signature is animated. However, on my local machine it just print the signature out in full and does not animate at all. Any idea why?

I have three files on my local host machine index.html (contains SVG code).js.js, style.css (code below). I tried using MAMP as well to see if it would work however still just prints out the name without animating. This is how my signature imports the other two files:
`<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head><body><script src="js.js"></script>
<div class="container"> <div class="signature"> SVG CODE </div></div></body>`

Any idea what could be the issue? Thank you!

Comment: Did you open the console.log to see what's wrong?

Comment: The codepen is also using Compass and SASS...

Comment: @Paulie_D how do you import these onto my machine? Do you think its libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there were two problems:

1) missing jQuery which is a dependancy for the javascript `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

2)While copying javascript from codepen, it was adding some addition checks whilst compiling the coffeescript. So just use http://js2.coffee/ in order to convert the coffeescript into javascript preview, which you can then use in your code.

After fixinf these two things, the code worked perfectly for me. Thank you @Guy for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are missing jQuery which is a dependancy for the javascript. Add the script above your other JS file:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You should also load JS last so your end structure would be something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container"> <div class="signature"> SVG CODE </div></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank - however this still does not solve the problem on my pc and is still the same- just appears with no animation :( So my signature.html file looks like this {<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container"> <div class="signature"> 
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="34.924 351.353 548.489 159.86">SVG STUFF</svg>
  </div></div>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
}

Comment: if you do a right click > inspect element and then look at the console do you have any errors?

Comment: The first one is "GET file://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js net::file not found" and second one is " and the second one is in the js file" $(document).ready(function () {
        window.signature.initialize();
        return $('button').on('click', function () {
            window.signature.initialize();
            return setTimeout(function () {
                return window.signature.animate();
            }, 500);
        });
    });
    $(window).load(function () {
        return window.signature.animate();
    });
}.call(this));" cant see the problem, can you?

Comment: Apologies, try adding 'https:' to the script src. I have updated my answer with the protocol added.

Comment: hmm... this seems to create a lot of "js.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shouldStopExecution' of undefined      for (i = 0, len = paths.length; i < len; i++) {
                    if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(1)) {
                        break;
                    }"                                                                                                                      Does that mean my javascript is incorrect or could it be a problem with the library (which I dont assume). Thanks once again

Comment: so it seems that when compiling the coffeescript CodePen adds some additional checks, thats what the `window.CP` object is. I would suggest copying the coffeescript code from codepen into http://js2.coffee/ and then adding the output from there

Comment: Genius!!! Thank you, worked perfectly fine after using js2.coffee

Comment: glad i could help. you can mark the answer as correct/vote it up so that others may find this useful.